# What is an adjective for a process that takes time?

Tags: word-request

I think there is a better (more formal) way to say this phrase:

> ... and it is obvious this is something that takes time.

I would like to reformulate it like so:

> ... and it is obvious is this a [word] process"

I'm thinking about `lengthy`, but this is often associated with something tedious, which may not necessarily be the case here. For context, the process is something similar to building a network of friends

Comment: **lengthy** need not entail tedium.

Answer (score 1):

It is a **gradual** progress, a **lengthy** process, a **protracted** process.

Answer (score 1):

"extensive" process.  Indicates it will take a long time but for good reason -  - many steps or complexities are in the process

If you want to focus just on time, use "lengthy"

If you want to point out the process takes a long time and you are proposing it be shortened, try "time-consuming"

Comment: I like "extensive"! Thank you! 
I thought about "time-consuming", but it has this "negative" feel to it which is not true for my process. I wouldn't say making friends is "time-consuming" :) It just takes a while.

Comment: Just a nitpick.  Since a process can be involuted, **extensive** seems "off".  Does a process *extend*?

Answer (score 0):

"time consuming" is commonly used in this instance.